# Getting pairs of angle and velocity for a projectile to a given destination

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I'm trying to calculate the initial velocity $v_0$ and angle $\theta$ for a given destination $(x, y)$ with a launch height of $y_0$. Obviously there will be a set of pairs of velocity and angle that will pass through the destination point. This set is given by
$$ \left\{(v_0,\theta) \middle|y = - \frac{g}{2 v_0^2 \cdot \cos^2(\theta)} \cdot x^2 + \tan(\theta) \cdot x +y_0 \right\} \ .$$

I have already looked at this questions:

[Solving for initial velocity required to launch a projectile to a given destination at a different height](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27992/solving-for-initial-velocity-required-to-launch-a-projectile-to-a-given-destinat)

[How to get the angle needed for a projectile to pass through a given point for trajectory plotting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56265/how-to-get-the-angle-needed-for-a-projectile-to-pass-through-a-given-point-for-t)

So for example I could rewrite the set to
$$\left\{ (v_0,\theta) \middle| v_0 = \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2} g x^2}{x \tan(\theta)+y_0}} \right\}\ .$$

Is there an easy way to compute this set for one given destination without iterating over all possible velocities or angles?

Comment: There is more than one solution. Choose an angle, arbitrarily if you like, and compute the velocity you need. So I don't understand what you mean by "iterating over all possible velocities or angles".

Comment: what are the other information provided related to the coordinate $(x,y)$

Comment: I want to calculate not only one pair of angle and velocity, I want to compute the set of pairs. For me the only way to proximate this set is to iterate over all angles and calculate the velocity or the other way around.
@Akash I don't know any thing else about the destination. In fact I know launch point and the destination.

Comment: then you could use this equation for the trajectory of the projectile in term's of &R&    $y$ = $x(1-\frac{x}{R})tan(\alpha)$  where $\alpha$ is the angle of projection

Comment: @Akash I have realy no idea want you mean. What is $R$, is it the range? What is the difference between $\theta$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: yes $R$ is the range and there is no difference in $\theta$ and $\alpha$  actually by mistake I placed & sign instead of $ that's why it is &R&

Comment: Is the equation $y=x(1-\frac{x}{R})\tan(\theta)$ for uneven ground? And if the destination is given by $(x,y)$, isn't the range $R$ equal to $x$?